# Unity. How do you identify what kind of prefab you are clicking?

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a seemingly very simple question regarding Unity that I have been wanting to ask.

In Unity (I use it for Hololens programming, but I suppose it is the same for other purposes), you have prefabs that you can use to put in your scene. Or you could create an object for example an empty object, a plane, a text etc.

When you create them, of course you know what they are. But what happens if you open a Scene that has been done by someone else. Say you open it and see a camera, a light and some objects. 
You click on an object and you can see its property in the Inspector window.

But how do you see what kind of object it is??

---

I am now using a library with a lot of types of buttons. They look similar but their behavior is quite different. So when I click on one I would like to know what type of object it is. But in the inspector window I only see its name and its elements but not its type. Which makes things problematic.

---

EDIT1:

For example I am now making a new project. I remember that in an old project I used some kind of Text. It worked nicely.

So I put a Text in this new project and it is completely different to the text in the old project. How can I know what i used in the old one to make the same in the current one? I have no idea

Comment: The type is `GameObject` for everything in Unity. I'm not sure to understand your question

Comment: e.g I have two kinds of buttons here. They have different properties and scripts assigned to them. I choose one and put it on my scene. Save it and leave the project for a month. Then I open it and have no idea what kind of button it originally was

Comment: @Z3RP Possible duplicate? I checked the link and has *absolutely nothing* even remotely related with this question

Comment: @KansaiRobot He asked how to check what type of button he clicked on.Or not ?

Comment: *Save it and leave the project for a month. Then I open it and have no idea what kind of button it originally was* That's what the comment/documentation are made for :)

Comment: @Cid Yes:) but take into account that I am not even coding anything. Just putting assets in the design windows (Hierarchy, etc)

Comment: @KansaiRobot You want to know wich type of button it is when the game is not started ? And not in the code.

Comment: @Z3RP in the editor

Comment: Ok sry for my dupe flag and for the comments. I completely understand you wrong

Comment: @KansaiRobot Naming is very important too. If you place some UI things named `button1`, `button2`, `button3`, `process_the_thingy` etc... don't cry if you don't remember why you placed them

Comment: @Cid So I guess I ll never know what kind of object I used for my text (see Edit) (sigh)

Comment: @KansaiRobot [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.GetPrefabType.html) may help you

Comment: Use prefab names, object tags or a monobehaviour that stores a "type" for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the question isn't that clear so i'll answer you in the easiest way:

> right click in hierarchy inspector on your object->select prefab
>   -this will select your prefab in your project window.

If this was not your question things get complicated, you have to extend your editor and implement this to compare gameObjects:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=netframework-4.7.2

If this again isn't what you want, well you have to add some meta data to your elements and identify them manualy.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your "what kind of prefab is it" problem, put this at the prefab root (and fill it in):

```
public class WhatAmI : MonoBehaviour {

    public string Name;

    [TextArea]
    public string Description;
}
```

To solve your "I started a new project" problem, just drag the prefabs from the old project hierarchy to the new one (and copy any other required files like meshes and materials).